# Moving multiple point features back to their original location?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, coordinates

[image]

Is there a way to move multiple point features in bulk back to their original location given their X,Y locations?

The red points and green points are from the same feature class, the only difference is that the red points were ran through the Geo processing wizard (which snaps all the points to the line) and the green points are the same feature class not ran through the Geo processing wizard.  The points highlighted in yellow are exactly the same in their schema and data including their x,y coordinates (which is odd because they visually appear to be in slightly different location.  I need to move the red points to their green counter part denoted by the bold label 'BVKYXXXXXXX).

Comment: What information do you have? Do you have a matching UID field in both tables (i.e., the feature class that you want to edit and the table containing the original coordinates)?

Comment: I'm working with points that are snapped to a line and need to be linear referenced to put them in a certain order.  Some of the points shouldn't be  snapped to the line but When I run the 'Route Event GeoProccessing Wizard" it snaps all the points to said line.  I then have to go through hundreds of points and manually move them back to their original location using the original dataset pre GeoProcessing Wizard.  Is there a way to move specific points from a feature class to another feature class with the same specific points without manually snapping point to point?

Comment: It would be easier to explain if I knew how to upload an image to this website lol.

Comment: If they shouldn't be on the line, then are you sure you need linear referencing in the first place? It sounds like all you need is to "put them in a certain order", but what does this mean? It sounds like you're saying that you need the points to be moved but also that you don't need the points to be moved. If you think a picture would help, look for the little picture icon (a mountain and a sun/moon) that should be just after the curly brackets and before the numbered list icon on the formatting toolbar, above the main textbox.

Comment: In arcgis it is one line of code in field calculator on field shape. arcpy. Point(x,y)

Comment: I added a picture and explained in further detail my problem.  Maybe that will shed more light on my problem?  I have extremely limited coding experience Felix so I'm not sure I could put that into action.

Comment: This would appear to be easy to do using ArcPy and there is no simple tool for it.